# When is html officially in "run-time"

Tags: html

I just had a discussion about meta tags in html and when they are interpreted by the web browser. My colleague was adament that this is done **pre-run-time (html parse time)** as **run-time** officially starts when `body.onload` is triggered.

When does **run-time** officially start in html?

I know this seems trivial, but googling "html run-time" yields naught.

Comment: You've also got the `DOMContentLoaded` event. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: I always assumed there is no run time, the browser parses it but it doesn't run as such.

Comment: `onload` happens quite late, after all the resources have been loaded and the DOM created. So all HTML parsing has already happened at that time.

Comment: @nevabyte - err, so how do you explain seeing output from `alert("some text");` or `console.log("some text");` - both of these statements need to be parsed and then executed - _very_ different to `<span>some text</span>`

Comment: That is javascipt though, I agree javascript runs and modifies the HTML, but HTML doesn't run at all, it is not a programming language to begin with.

Comment: @nevabyte - ahh, okay - I see the distinction that you're making.. Certainly, the language contained in the question is conducive to ambiguity.

Comment: @nevabyte That is a very good point, and when I originally asked this question I did consider the inclusion of javascript however the question does not reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [nevatype](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7391763/nevabyte), "run-time" doesn't exactly make sense for declarative languages like HTML. That's why you aren't getting any Google results.

---

What you're asking about sounds sort of like the rendering pipeline:

> - Parsing, which turns a chunk of HTML into DOM nodes
> - Style, which resolves CSS onto the DOM
> - Layout, which figures out where DOM elements end up relative to one another
> - Paint setup, sometimes referred to as recording, which converts styled DOM elements into a display list (SkPicture) of drawing commands to paint later, on a per-layer basis
> - Painting, which converts the SkPicture of drawing commands into pixels in a bitmap somewhere (either in system memory or on the GPU if using Ganesh)
> - Compositing, which assembles all layers into a final screen image
>
> <sub>Source: https://www.chromium.org/developers/the-rendering-critical-path</sub>

However, as noted on that same page, **this is *not* how browsers do the initial page load**.

---

HTML is a funny language. Browsers will basically let you do almost anything.

Imagine writing sloppy C code and the compiler goes, "You know, George, you have totally no idea what a pointer is. But I like you, George. Here's what you probably meant."<sup>[1]</sup>

That's almost how HTML gets handled. When a browser interprets HTML, it is *extremely* kind. No closing tags? No credit? No problem!

Basically, the browser starts progressively rendering the page while it is still loading.

This is the reason the XHTML craze a few years back was so weird. XHTML is not forgiving. You had to get the entire document and parse it before the browser started showing anything. Yuck.

<sub>1: Just so nobody gets the wrong idea, if C did do that it would not be a good thing.</sub>

---

[This](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/) and [this](https://medium.com/@luisvieira_gmr/understanding-the-critical-rendering-path-rendering-pages-in-1-second-735c6e45b47a) describe the initial page load in an understandable way.

---

Here's a rough idea:

1. Make a request
2. Receive responses with the HTML
3. Parse the HTML into a DOM tree (happens *while the page is still loading*)
4. Style the DOM nodes (using the browser's user agent stylesheet)
5. Layout (figuring out where DOM elements are)
6. Paint the layers
7. Composite the layers onto the screen

This is fairly similar to the pipeline before, but the parsing is happening aggressively, and I haven't gotten to the external resources yet.

So your page has external resources. That's expected. The browser expects it. The browser will use a [preloader](https://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/) in the background to scan ahead of the parser and start loading those external links. So step 3 part A is preloading resources.

Except that you have [blocking CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css) in your HTML. That's okay. Everybody does it. <sub>(Except the magic unicorns at Google who <s>telepathically transmit</s> actually *include* the important parts of the CSS in the HTML, thus eliminating a resource request.)</sub>

CSS links are blocking by default. The browser cannot render until the CSS has been loaded, parsed into CSSOM, and then used to style nodes.

I'm not very clear on whether the CSS also blocks the HTML parsing or whether it happens concurrently (maybe a second thread?).

So here's where I see:

1. Make a request
2. Receive responses with the HTML
3. Parse the HTML into a DOM tree (happens *while the page is still loading*)

   - Meet a CSS `<link>` and load that *(and while we're waiting, the preloader starts looking for other resources to load)*
   - Parse CSS into a CSSOM tree
4. Style the DOM nodes using the CSSOM
5. Layout (figuring out where DOM elements are)
6. Paint the layers
7. Composite the layers onto the screen

---

*Now*, you tell me you have render blocking JavaScript. That's really, really bad.

When the parser meets a `<script>` tag that is not `async` or `defer`, it *has* to get that JavaScript run, because that JavaScript could be [making changes to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) (but nobody in their right mind does this anymore).

So now we *have* to stop parsing the DOM, wait for the JS to download, parse it, then execute it.

1. Make a request
2. Receive responses with the HTML
3. Parse the HTML into a DOM tree (happens *while the page is still loading*)

   - Meet a CSS `<link>` and load that *(and while we're waiting, the preloader starts looking for other resources to load)*
   - Parse CSS into a CSSOM tree
   - JavaScript! Abort! Shut everything down!

     1. Wait for the JavaScript to arrive *(the preloader is the only guy still doing anything)*
     2. Receive *all* the JavaScript (JavaScript is not as kind as HTML)
     3. Parse the JavaScript
     4. Run the JavaScript (may or may not change the DOM)
4. Parse the rest of the HTML into the DOM
5. Style the DOM nodes using the CSSOM
6. Layout (figuring out where DOM elements are)
7. Paint the layers
8. Composite the layers onto the screen

---

To answer your question about when run-time is: I have parsing at step 3, but the DOM gets used through step 8 (and keeps getting used when users initiate changes).

The load event happens [when the document and all the dependent resources have been loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load). Since this includes things such as images, you could stick the load event around step 10.